# Cannot add the assembly System.Collections.Concurrent as using in Xamarin PCL project

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, mscorlib

I can see my Xamarin PCL project has the NET library added to it.

[.Net library in pcl references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otsLZ.png)

So I view in the Object explorer and I can see 2 versions of my mscorlib. [2.0.5.0] and [4.0.0.0].

[duplicate libraries of CSharp and mscorlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKJt3.png)

And if you check I have a duplicate of similar version for my CSharp library also.
I am assuming that its automatically pointing towards the [2.0.5.0] version.

But interestingly my android project in the same solution has mscorlib directly refrenced in the references section and yes I can access my System.Collections.Concurrent library in my android project.

But I need to access it in my Xamarin project.
I need a way to add that assembly in my PCL project too. Any one any idea?

Comment: Xamarin is moving to .NET Standard 2.0, so plan your migration.

Comment: @LexLi: Thanx. Your comment actually helped. +1

Answer (score 1):

LexLi's comment actually got me thinking. So here's what I did. Hopefully this is going to be helpful.

1. I checked my VS2017 (Professional) version, and it was pending three updates. 
   Latest(as of now) is 15.4.4.4, got that updated.
2. I created a fresh Xamarin cross platform application with the same name (obviously a different location).
3. Got all the nuget packages that I needed. (Its better you do it manually for each project, because this has a lot of version compatibility dependencies).
4. And then fetched all the class files into this from my previous application. (Make sure you create the required folder structures). I double checked the app configs and package files to make sure everything is identical.
5. Fixed my Android manifest file by making changes in android Project(Right Click) >> Properties >> Android Manifest.
6. Do check your AppDelegate file in iOS and your App.xaml.cs file in UWP. Because sometimes some plugins require some changes in these. So make sure you have them exactly the way they were before.

And that was it. All for fixing the Object Model and Concurrent Collections issue. But in the process I got a nice migration done for my app.

If you want you can directly add projects to your solution but I'm not sure if that'll work because I haven't tried that.

Comment: Impressive steps to migrate your code base. Nice try and hope it helps much more persons in the future.